# Computer does not have USB001 Virtual Printer Port for USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, printer

Win 7 Pro x64 machine on a company domain network does not have the ability to add a USB printer for some reason. All other computers do.

In the Add Local Printer section, there's no USB001 (Virtual Printer Port for  USB) option.

I tried doing several Google searches, found a few tricks, but nothing seems to work. I created a local port, labeled it USB001 and installed the driver, but the printer does not print anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, what happens when you plug in the printer - does the OS detect it?

Comment: The HP built-in Utility asks me to install it. However, it fails during the install.

Comment: Any error message or details as to why? What does event viewer suggest (if anything)?

Comment: No error message. Just says to unplug printer, shut off, turn on, then plug back in and try again

Comment: Event log doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

That port is only created when you install a USB printer. It's not there by default. Follow the manufacturers instructions for your printer installation.

Comment: I tried installing the driver from HP's web site, from the CD it came with, and from when you plug in the printer, it has that built-in driver install feature. None of those options work. At some point during the install, it fails.

Comment: Go to device manager and see if there are any warning on printer or usb devices. Point that device to your printer driver.

Comment: Nothing appears in DM related to the printer

Comment: Ok, then unplug all of your USB devices from the machine. Uninstall all USB devices from device manager, reboot, after your system devices reinstall plug the printer back in.

Comment: Tried that and still won't install. Even did a system restore going back 2 days ago. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the USB devices.
When reinstalling the USB Printing Support, choose the driver to install. Search location C:\Windows\inf

That did it on mine!

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while, I found no real answer.  And it's not really answered here yet.  So I decided to try something.

Even though my printer installation instructions say NOT to plug it in before installation, I decided to anyway.
My reasoning was that USB always seems to use pnp and install drivers the first time you use a device.
I don't remember ever using a USB to parallel cable, so I guessed that's why a USB local port didn't appear in the list.

Viola - It worked!  And I am connecting an OLD Brother IntelliFax 4100.  And now the USB port appears in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to uninstall the USB to Serial drivers that I installed.

Specifically the PL2303_Prolific_DriverInstaller_v1_14_0.